# History configuration? (404s)

Tags: stellar-core

I'm attempting to get a full-history horizon & core setup going, and I'm running into 404s fetching history buckets, with every combination of configurations I've seen on stackexchange and in the github issues.

In brief (the simplest steps I would expect to work), I followed the directions for a persistent server here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/stellar/quickstart/

Set CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true, and uncommented the lines below:

```
# Stellar.org history store
[HISTORY.sdf1]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.sdf2]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.sdf3]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

Curl returns '22'; strace confirms that history.stellar.org is returning a 404 page for all requests.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have applied HTTP method at an obsolete path. As I observe from the official example config, https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_example.cfg#L366

```
 get="curl http://history.stellar.org/{0} -o {1}"
```

You may refer to the format there, around line 366.

```
 #other examples:
 [HISTORY.stellar]
 get="curl http://history.stellar.org/{0} -o {1}"
 put="aws s3 cp {0} s3://history.stellar.org/{1}"

 [HISTORY.backup]
 get="curl http://backupstore.blob.core.windows.net/backupstore/{0} -o {1}"
 put="azure storage blob upload {0} backupstore {1}"

 #The history store of the Stellar testnet
 [HISTORY.h1]
 get="curl -sf http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_001/{0} -o {1}"

 [HISTORY.h2]
 get="curl -sf http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_002/{0} -o {1}"

 [HISTORY.h3]
 get="curl -sf http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

Comment: I should have specified that I've seen that file and tried those lines, in various combination.  Here: https://pastebin.com/8dYELkTC is a debug-level log (with some filtering) of what happens when I use the line you point to.  It's unclear from the log, but I know from past attempts that strace would show it's a 404, and if I copy a url from the log into a browser I do get a 404.

Comment: Could you provide your Stellar-core version?

Comment: It's the one installed as part of the docker quickstart; as of yesterday: 10.1.0

Comment: `[History ERROR] error loading history state: rapidjson internal assertion failure: IsObject() [GetHistoryArchiveStateWork.cpp:72]` likely means that you are getting a null object. Could you confirm if your ports are in/outward bounded accordingly?

Comment: As I mentioned, I used strace to determine that the error is because it's processing the text of a 404 page, which is not a json object.  Also, I get a 404 for the url outside the container, but I can verify that all outbound traffic is allowed; inbound is only allowed to 8000.